# how to access the properties of the host activity from a fragment dialog (kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

i have this fragment dialog and i want to edit some host activity properties when he click on btnOk in line 26 can any one help me or give me another way to communicate between a dialog fragment and its host activity
`

```
package com.exemple.tic_tac_toe

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import android.app.Activity




class restartDialog : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val layout : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exit_layout , container , false)
        this.isCancelable = false
        val btnOk : Button = layout.findViewById(R.id.btnYes)
        val btnNo : Button = layout.findViewById(R.id.btnNO)
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(){
            dismiss()
            /////here acces the host activity properties and change them
        }
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(){
            dismiss()
        }
        return  layout
    }
}
```

`

Comment: where is error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better approach would be to use an interface or a callback, rather than having the DialogFragment access the Activity properties.

You can create an interface:

```
interface DialogClickListener {
    fun dialogOkClicked()
    fun dialogCancelClicked()
}
```

Make the hosting Activity implement it:

```
class YourActivity: AppCompatActivity(), DialogClickListener {
    
    override fun dialogOkClicked() {
    
    }

    override fun dialogCancelClicked() {
    
    }
}
```

And in your DialogFragment, call those methods in case the Activity implements them:

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(){
    (activity as? DialogClickListener)?.dialogOkClicked()
    dismiss()
    
}
btnNo.setOnClickListener(){
    (activity as? DialogClickListener)?.dialogCancelClicked()
    dismiss()
}
```

This would allow you to use this DialogFragment in other places and not inside a specific hosting Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared view model to achieve this.
Make a viewModel and create instance of that viewModel in your Activity.

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
   private val _sharedData = MutableLiveData<Event<Int,Any>>() // Int is type and Any is Data
   val sharedData : LiveData<Event<Int,Any>> get() = _sharedData

  fun setData(type : Int, data : Any) {
     sharedData.value = Event(type, data)
  }
}
```

you can get the event class from here
https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af

you can register your viewModel in Activity

```
private val mViewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()
```

and get the instance of your viewModel in fragment/dialog fragment

```
private val mHomeViewModel by activityViewModels<HomeViewModel>()
```

when you want to send data

```
mHomeViewModel.setData(your_type,your_data)
```

and in your activity observe viewModel

```
mViewModel.observe(this,EventObserver{
 // you will get the data here with corresponding type
})
```

for more info you can check the official documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Answer (score 0):

**restartDialog.kt:**

```
package com.exemple.tic_tac_toe

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import android.app.Activity

class restartDialog(
    private val someTextView: TextView
) : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val layout : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exit_layout , container , false)
        this.isCancelable = false
        val btnOk : Button = layout.findViewById(R.id.btnYes)
        val btnNo : Button = layout.findViewById(R.id.btnNO)
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(){
            dismiss()
            /////here acces the host activity properties and change them
            someTextView.text  = "text will change"
        }
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(){
            dismiss()
        }
        return  layout
    }
}
```

**MainActivty.kt:**

```
package com.exemple.tic_tac_toe
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val someText : TextView = findViewById(R.id.someText)
        val btndialog : Button = findViewById(R.id.btndialog)
        val restartDialog= restartDialog(someText)
        btndialog .setOnClickListener(){
        if (!restartDialog.isAdded) {
                restartDialog.show(childFragmentManager, "")
            }
          }
     }
}
```